# binding properly FILE C structure in Fortran

Tags: fortran, posix, interop

I wanted to know if someone did managed to bind the C struct FILE in fortran in a proper way. I tried the following on gfortran (beware that fnum is gnu extension)

```
program test_fdopen
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  type, bind(C) :: file_type
    character(c_char) :: data(216) ! find compiling #include <stdio.h> int main() { printf("%d", sizeof(FILE)); }
  end type 

  type(file_type) :: fp
  integer(c_int) :: first
  character(len=3) :: mode

  interface
   
   function fdopenf(num_desc, mode) bind(C,name="fdopen") result(desc)
    use iso_c_binding
    import :: file_type
    integer(c_int) :: num_desc
    character(c_char), intent(in) :: mode(*)
    type(file_type) ::desc
   end function


   function fgetcf(desc) bind(C,name="fgetc") result(one_char)
    use iso_c_binding
    import :: file_type
    type(file_type), intent(in) ::desc
    integer(c_int) :: one_char
   end function

  end interface
  
   call execute_command_line("echo coucou > haha.txt")
   open(unit=22, file="haha.txt", action="read")
   mode = "r" // char(0)
   fp = fdopenf(fnum(22), mode)
   first = fgetcf(fp)  
   print *, char(first), first

    close(22)

end program test_fdopen
```

I wanted to avoid to hardcode the length `216`, but sadly I did not find a standard way to do that

Comment: "I wanted to know if someone did manage" is a poll, not an SO question. These kinds of C structures are better accessed indirectly using opaque pointers and not operated on directly in Fortran

Comment: regarding to manipulate that C pointer in fortran, I agree with you that job must be on the C side instead of fortran, but I did not want to add C code to the original code, so I wanted to try this weird solution

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that all the libc functions that use the FILE struct never handle it by value, it's always a pointer. E.g. `fopen()` returns a pointer to a FILE struct. You never need to dereference that pointer and then copy the FILE struct somewhere, you only need to keep track of the pointer.

Thus, in your Fortran code, as alluded to in a comment, you never need to store the FILE struct either, only the pointer to it. Thus, with `ISO_C_BINDING` the thing you need is the builtin `type(C_PTR)`.

A fixed version of the code:

```
program test_fdopen
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none

  type(c_ptr) :: fp
  integer(c_int) :: first
  character(len=3) :: mode

  interface
   
   function fdopenf(num_desc, mode) bind(C,name="fdopen") result(desc)
    use iso_c_binding
    integer(c_int), value :: num_desc
    character(c_char), intent(in) :: mode(*)
    type(c_ptr) ::desc
   end function

   function fgetcf(desc) bind(C,name="fgetc") result(one_char)
    use iso_c_binding
    type(c_ptr), intent(in), value ::desc
    integer(c_int) :: one_char
   end function

  end interface
  
  call execute_command_line("echo coucou > haha.txt")
  open(unit=22, file="haha.txt", action="read")
  mode = "r" // char(0)
  fp = fdopenf(fnum(22), mode)
  first = fgetcf(fp)  
  print *, char(first), first
  close(22)
end program test_fdopen
```

In addition to the use of `type(c_ptr)`, one also has to pass the fd argument to `fdopen` by value, and same for the `type(c_ptr)` argument to `fgetc`.

Comment: I replaced the return value of C binded functions by a `type(c_ptr)` instead of `type(file_type)` but it does not seems to be allocated when the functions are returning

Comment: @aitzkora: I added a working example to the answer. You also have to be careful about using the value attribute when appropriate.

Comment: thanks @janneb : never forget the "value" attribute, this must become a mantra for me when I use iso_c_binding !